# Form has different style when shown from MMC snap-in

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mmc

I'm displaying a dialog in an MMC snap-in. When the dialog is called from the result pane it has the Windows theme.

[image: Screenshot of buttons when called from the result pane]

However when the dialog is called from the snap-in scope pane context menu it has a different style.

[image: Screenshot of buttons when called from context menu]

The snap-in is written in C++ and the dialog is a C# form. The C++ code calls the C# code via COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [`Application.EnableVisualStyles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) enables visual styles for your application. In an application the method is called usually in `Main` method of your application. But in this case, you can call `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in constructor of form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
}
```

> [Application.EnableVisualStyles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> This method enables visual styles for the application. Visual styles
>   are the colors, fonts, and other visual elements that form an
>   operating system theme. Controls will draw with visual styles if the
>   control and the operating system support it. To have an effect,
>   EnableVisualStyles() must be called before creating any controls in
>   the application; typically, EnableVisualStyles() is the first line in
>   the Main function.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.